# Docker virtual host cached

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose, dinghy

I'm using `Docker` with `VirtualBox` and `dinghy` and `docker-compose`.
I'm creating a container via `docker-compose`. The following is the `docker-compose.yml` config.

```
rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:3-management
  ports:
    - "15672:15672"
    - "5672:5672"
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: 'rabbitmq.docker'
    VIRTUAL_PORT: 15672
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: docker
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: docker
```

Everything works great. I can enter the management page of `RabbitMQ` by visiting the url `rabbitmq.docker:15672` and the user `docker` is configured correctly.

I wanted to experiment a little so I removed the `environment` section. I deleted the image and the container and built/run it again. 
The thing that I don't understand is this, I could still visit the management page using the same uri, although I did not specify a virtual host this time.

The resulting `yml` file is this

```
rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:3-management
  ports:
    - "15672:15672"
    - "5672:5672"
```

What have I missed? Since I no longer specify a virtual host this, to my understanding, shouldn't be happening. Is there a way to see all the virtual hosts that `Docker` is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to see all the virtual hosts that Docker is using?

You are misunderstanding the term "Virtual Host" in this context. Docker has no notion of virtual hosts at all. In this context, the term *Virtual Host*  is specific to RabbitMQ (or rather AMQP, which is implemented by RabbitMQ). This is documentated in the [RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html) (emphasis mine):

> [...] the "virtual host" (or vhost) [...] specifies the namespace for entities (exchanges and queues) referred to by the protocol. **Note that this is not virtual hosting in the HTTP sense.**

When using the `rabbitmq` Docker image, the management UI will *always be accessible under **any** hostname*, regardless of your `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable (as long as you're using the `3-management` tag of that image).

I recommend a thorough reading of the [documentation of the `rabbitmq` Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/). There you will see that the image supports an environment variable named `RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST`. **The variables `VIRTUAL_HOST` and `VIRTUAL_PORT` are not evaluated in any way by this image and do not have any effect at all.**

Comment: `the management UI will always be accessible under any hostname`, what do you mean?

Comment: That it's unimportant which HTTP hostname you use for the management UI, be it `rabbitmq.docker`, then container's IP or any other hostname. If you're mapping port 15672 to localhost, `http://localhost:15672` will also do fine, the same as `http://127.0.0.1:15672` or `http://[::1]:15672`.

Comment: That's what I understood, but I wanted to make sure.  Have you tested this?  Because for me this is not the case. I've already tested this possibility and the only HTTP hostnames that work are the container's ip (which is expected) and `rabbitmq.docker`.

Comment: Moreover I wanted to ask about this `The variables VIRTUAL_HOST and VIRTUAL_PORT are not evaluated in any way by this image and do not have any effect at all.`. Do you have any resources so I can read more about this? I've seen the setup that I'm using in a number of examples with `docker-compose` and this is used. So if what you are saying is correct, I need to understand by what these variables are evaluated, what is their purpose. Maybe what you are saying is true with vanilla `Docker`, I really don't know, but I'm using the `docker-compose` tool and maybe there are differencies.

Comment: I've googled a bit about this; the `VIRTUAL_HOST` env variable is typically only used by the [`jwilder/nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) image. Any possibility that you're using this image?

Comment: Ok now this makes sense. The tool I'm using (`dinghy`) uses this underneath. `Dinghy will run a HTTP proxy inside a docker container in the VM, giving you easy access to web apps running in other containers. This uses the excellent nginx-proxy docker tool.`

Comment: If you want you can include all this new information to your answer and I will accept it. Thank you for your help so far. All these aspects plus the fact that I'm using Docker only for one week made everything complicated.